# Stitch scanned images using CLI

Tags: scanning, command-line, panorama, image-processing

I have scanned a newspaper article which was larger than the scanner glass. Each page was scanned twice: the top and the bottom parts, where the middle part appeared in both images.

Is there a way to quickly match and stitch these scanned images, preferably using CLI? The panorama stitching tools I know require lengthy configuration, which is mostly irrelevant: lens size, focus, angle etc.

Hugin has a [solution for this issue](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/tutorials/scans/en.shtml), but it isn't practical for batch jobs.

Comment: Your "hugin *solution for this issue*" uses the GUI interface.. `hugin-tools` has a CLI tool-set.. maybe you can do something with them (unless those CLI tools what you meant by "not practical".. )

Comment: Any CLI solution is welcome.

Answer (score 4):

You could play around with [ImageMagick's](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) `montage` tool. You'll want to install the [imagemagick](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/imagemagick)
 package before you go any further.

At face value, you just need to ply `montage` with input files and then give it an output file:

```
montage scan1.jpg scan2.jpg output.jpg
```

but `montage` can get *really* powerful. You can pass along various translation arguments if you need to rotate the pages before they're combined. You can read [an extended manual on it here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/).

Comment: It simply concatenates images, without smart stitching (matching points, rotating a bit etc.)

Comment: Beware this command will output a low-resolution file.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, in really what you need is ImageMagick, install it `sudo apt-get install imagemagick` and then you just need to do these steps:

- create a blank image in the parameters to fit the two images that you need to put together.
- type in the terminal: `composite -gravity North top_scan.jpg blank_image.jpg top_image.jpg`
- type in the terminal: `composite -gravity South bottom_scan.jpg top_image.jpg complete_image.jpg`

But if you need something that autorotate the images to get them perfectly matching, sorry, but as far as I know there isn't anything that do it in ubuntu.

Comment: There is one: http://www.panoramatools.com/

Answer (score 0):

In CLI, you should look at [panorama tools](http://www.panoramatools.com/), as Hugin is only a GUI for this software.

Comment: Pointing in the right direction, but not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would use convert from imagemagick

if you see the 2 examples below and play around it will be VERY easy to do what you requested [you may have to make 2 then stitch those]:

NOTA BENE:    -append gives your vertical and +append horizontal
-geometry allows you to state what size your final image ...

> convert *.JPG -append  -geometry 1920x1200  final.jpg

> convert hey.png hey2.png hey3.png +append final.png